# web application using JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Why is the username being retyped each time the client logs in:

```
<%
String userName = request.getParameter("username");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
String rm_me = request.getParameter("rm_me");
String rm_uname = request.getParameter("rm_uname");
if (userName != null && password != null) {
if (rm_me != null) {
Cookie ckU = new Cookie("username", userName);
Cookie ckP = new Cookie("password", password);
response.addCookie(ckP);
} else {
if (rm_uname != null) {
Cookie ckU = new Cookie("username", userName);
}
}
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
if (cookies != null) {
for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
if (cookies[i].getName().equals("username")) {
userName = cookies[i].getValue();
}
if (cookies[i].getName().equals("password")) {
password = cookies[i].getValue();
}
}
}
%>
```

Comment: So, this is not your own code at all?

Comment: Storing the user's password in plain text in a cookie (or anywhere, for that matter) is a **Bad Idea**.

Answer (score 0):

Could it because of the browser's auto-form-filing feature ( http://www.ehow.com/how_7503496_clear-browser-autofill-forms.html )?

Answer (score 0):

It is because this is what your code does. If parameters are not sent and cookies are not set you do not see anything in your form. But if user once typed user name and pushed submit button the user/password are stored in cookie.

Now if use comes again to the form without parameters the data is read from cookies anyway and used to initiate values of `userName` and `password`.

```
if (cookies[i].getName().equals("username")) {
userName = cookies[i].getValue();
}
```

Then I believe these values are used to initiate values in form. You have not sent this code but that is my feeling.